# Using Pop-ups in Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, popup, popup-window

I've seen alot of answers on this subject but nothing I can use. 
I've created a flow that grabs the next available phone number from a library of numbers housed in an separate object in Salesforce then populates the number in a phone field on the Account. There are two types of numbers - Standard and Toll Free. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the user click a button that says "Assign a DID" on the Account record, have a pop-up that asks them to choose what type of number they want - Standard or Toll Free - then grab the next available number and assign it. 
Does anyone know how to accomplish this without having to write Apex code?

I'd also like to have a pop-up directly before the flow grabs next available number that says "Are you sure you want to assign this number to the account?" as an extra layer of making sure users think before they get click happy.

Any suggestions on where to look to find steps or other information based on this type of scenario?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Flows defined as a quick action (button on the detail page of a record) already appear as a pop-up (modal). Is your flow embedded in the lightning page and you are wanting to have pop-ups in the middle of the process? Usually, the easiest way to accomplish confirmation in a flow is to add a new screen in between screens and handle the process all within the flow. If you are in fact embedding the flow and wanting a pop up to confirm, you likely will need a custom lightning component and front end coding to achieve it. Also, please correct me if you are using classic.

Comment: Would this be of help? https://unofficialsf.com/show-toast-flow-action/
(I have no experience with it myself)